# How to send an alert from node.js express function

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hi and thanks in advance,

I am using the following function in my main.js to send a contact us email. Upon success I am simply redirecting back to home.

How do I send the client a simple alert("Email Sent: Success"); to the client browser.

from main.js

```
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.get('/sendMail', function(req, res){

 res.sendFile("index.html"); // html file is within public directory
});


    app.post('/sendMail',function(req,res){
   var username = req.body.name;
   var subject = req.body.subject;
   var fromEmail = req.body.email;
   var toEmail = 'support@domain.my';
   var bodyMessage = req.body.message;

  //  var htmlData = 'Hello:  ' + toEmail;

var mg = new Mailgun('key-0000000000000000000');
mg.sendText(fromEmail, toEmail,
  'CS: '+subject,
  bodyMessage,
  fromEmail, {},
  function(err) {
    if (err)res.send('NOT SENT: STRUGGLE EVERYDAY');
    else res.redirect('/');
    // res.json({success: true});
    // else     res.send('Success: EMAIL SENT From: '+fromEmail+'  -  To: '+toEmail);
}); 

});
```

from my index.html page button to send..

```
<!-- START CONTACT FORM -->

            <form method="POST" action="sendMail" accept-charset="UTF-8" class="contact-form" id="jvalidate" novalidate="novalidate"> 

                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                        <div class="field-holder">
                            <input class="form-control input-lg field" placeholder="John Snow" name="name" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                        <div class="field-holder">
                            <input class="form-control input-lg field" placeholder="yourEmail@Address.com" name="email" type="email">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-4">
                        <div class="field-holder">
                            <input class="form-control input-lg field" placeholder="Subject" name="subject" type="text">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-12 col-xs-12">
                        <div class="field-holder">
                            <textarea class="form-control" placeholder="Some text" name="message" cols="50" rows="10"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-12">  
                            <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert" style="display: none;">
                                Message has been successfully sent.
                            </div>
                            <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" style="display: none;">
                                <div class="alert-text">Server error</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-contact" type="submit" value="SEND MESSAGE">SEND MESSAGE</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <!-- END CONTACT FORM -->
```

If code does not allow it, are there any modules I can install for this ?

New to node and js. Thanks for the help.

Comment: You can't. Node runs server side. You can however send a response, for which the client code responds with an alert.

Comment: `res.send('<script>alert("Hello")</script>')` <- tada

Comment: @adeneo That's a really bad recommendation.  Don't unnecessarily tie the server-side components to the client-side.

Comment: @Brad - oh, it's just a joke. The OP is doing a regular form submit, so I guess just outputting the appropriate response in the `sendMail` route is the way to go.

Answer (score 4):

```
res.json({success: true});
```

At the front end, you get response in using `promise(JavaScript,jQuery,AngularJs..Whatever)` and check for `success` property for your further businedd logic.

Comment: I was toying/trying that but I couldn't quite get it to work.  my index.html page is using a standard button. I will update my question if that helps.

Comment: not html will not help.Update Q with JS sending `sendMail` request and relative part

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN No need for the JSON payload.  A simple `204 No Content` will do.  The client should be checking the response status code, and the promise will resolve/reject accordingly.

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN updated the questions with the full function.  not sure what a promise function is ( I assume it's like a callback ?). A brief example would be appreciated. thanks.

Comment: @Brad but API should be written in that way.HTTP Status can do this things.I am answering his requirement.I will prefer your solution.Most robust and stable

Comment: @RIYAJKHAN Better to have an API that properly uses HTTP status codes.  That might be what you're trying to say and I'm not understanding... but yes, if you use HTTP correctly, you don't need the duplicate `success: true`, and you can skip all the extra code needed to check it.